# How to record and encode a mp3 in an electron app?

Tags: node.js, audio, web-audio-api

I simply want to record audio and output an mp3.

I can't figure out what I need to do to make this code work:
I am recording audio in the renderer process using the web audio api. This works as expected.

```
app.tsx:

let mediaRecorder: MediaRecorder | null = null
let recordedChunks: Blob[] = []

 window.api.startVoiceRecording(() => {
      navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({ audio: true })
        .then((stream) => {
          mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream)

          mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', (event) => {
            recordedChunks.push(event.data)
          })

          mediaRecorder.onstop = async (e) => {
            const audioData = new Blob(recordedChunks, { type: 'audio/mp3' })
            // send audiodata to main to encode the mp3 (chrome doesn't support it)
            const buffer = await audioData.arrayBuffer()
            window.api.onNewMp3Blob(buffer)

            recordedChunks = []
            mediaRecorder = null
          }

          mediaRecorder.start()
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.error('Error accessing microphone:', err)
        })
    })

    window.api.stopVoiceRecording(() => {
      // if we are recording
      if (mediaRecorder) {
        mediaRecorder.stop()
        console.log('stopped, these are the cunks:' + recordedChunks.length)
      }
    })
```

This data arrives in main through ipc:

```
voice.ts:

ipcMain.on('c-onNewMp3Blob', (event, args: ArrayBuffer) => {
  const mp3encoder = new lamejs.Mp3Encoder(1, 44100, 128) //mono 44.1khz encode to 128kbps
  const mp3Data = []

  let mp3Tmp = mp3encoder.encodeBuffer(new Int16Array(44100)) //encode mp3

  mp3Data.push(Buffer.from(mp3Tmp))

  // Get end part of mp3
  mp3Tmp = mp3encoder.flush()


  // mp3Data contains now the complete mp3Data
  mp3Data.push(Buffer.from(mp3Tmp))


  // create a buffer from the mp3 data
  const buffer = Buffer.concat(mp3Data)

  // write the buffer to a file
  fs.writeFile(path.join(os.homedir(), 'result.mp3'), buffer, (err) => {
    if (err) console.log(err)
  })
})
```

Instead of encoding `new Int16Array(44100)`, which is one second of silence, I want to encode the args(ArrayBuffer passed through ipc), which is the recorded audio.

Here is a minmal example : https://github.com/vothvovo/recordtomp3